# Schema change not working

Tags: xml, relaxng

I have a schema called a.rnc that looks like this

```
default namespace = "urn:schemas-foo:bar"
include "b.rnc" {
        start = A
        Links = element link { HidableLinkType }*
    }

A = element Bat { AType }

AType = SavedResourceType 
                & Boundary?
                & Baz*
                & element link { HidableLinkType }*
```

I have another schema called b.rnc that used to look like this

```
default namespace = "urn:schemas-foo:bar"
include "c.rnc"
include "d.rnc" {
        start = Baz
    }

Baz = element Z { BType }

BType = SavedResourceType

SavedResourceType &= Boundary?
                  &  element panel-id { text }?
                  &  Annotations?                          

Boundary = element boundary { "a" | "b" | Bounds }

Bounds = (
        attribute from { xsd:date },
        attribute to { xsd:date }
    )
```

But I changed the last bit (as the xml structure has changed) to be

```
Boundary = element boundary { Bounds }

    Bounds = (
            attribute from { "a" | "b" | xsd:date },
            attribute to { "a" | "b" | xsd:date }
        )
```

I've generated the rng files but when the bit of code runs that validates against these schemas I get the following error

```
POST <url> 400 (Invalid attribute value is found. Value = 'a' Expected elements are: . line 7, column 13   Validated using schema:   b.rng)
```

Am I doing something silly here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Were you connected to your local machine which had the updated schema on or were you connected to a remote server which was out of date when you made the validation request?

You should stop pasting the code you're working on before altering any of it. That's just being lazy. And you could get fired for that.

Answer (score 1):

The reduced schema

```
start = element boundary { Bounds }

Bounds = (
    attribute from { "published" | "global" | xsd:date },
    attribute to { "published" | "global" | xsd:date }
)
```

validates this XML snippet just fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<boundary from="published" to="published"/>
```

Can you intercept your XML (after conversion from JSON), to see if it looks okay?

Comment: This might be hard to troubleshoot without knowing what the XML that is being validated looks like.

Comment: Can you let us know what fixed the problem?